# Why doesn't echo -n work in shell on Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, sh

The man page for `echo` says:

```
 -n    Do not print the trailing newline character.  This may also be
       achieved by appending `\c' to the end of the string, as is done by
       iBCS2 compatible systems.  Note that this option as well as the
       effect of `\c' are implementation-defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001
       (``POSIX.1'') as amended by Cor. 1-2002.  Applications aiming for
       maximum portability are strongly encouraged to use printf(1) to
       suppress the newline character.
```

However this doesn't seem to work in `sh` on Mac:

```
sh-3.2$ echo $0
/bin/sh
sh-3.2$ which echo
/bin/echo
sh-3.2$ echo -n foo
-n foo
```

It works properly in `bash`:

```
bash-3.2$ echo $0
bash
bash-3.2$ which echo
/bin/echo
bash-3.2$ echo -n foo
foobash-3.2
```

FWIW this only seems to happen on Mac, on Linux it works properly:

```
$ echo $0
sh
$ echo -n foo
foo$
```

Comment: If the shell provides a built-in `echo`, it'll run that instead of `/bin/echo` – check with `type echo` instead of `which echo` to see if it's a built-in.

Comment: Ah, thanks. It was confusing because I assumed `man echo` was pulling up the correct version.

Comment: Macs are not FreeBSD. Macs are UNIX and OSX though they do contain components of FreeBSD userland.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-n` is a `bash` extension to `echo`. In version 3.2 (which ships with macOS), `bash` does not support the extension when invoked as `sh`. Starting with version 4.0 (some version of which is likely on your Linux box), `bash` *does* honor `-n` when invoked as `sh`.

Update: the `xpg_echo` option determines if `bash`'s built-in `echo` is POSIX-compliant or not. In `bash` 3.2 (or at least the macOS build of 3.2), this option defaults to on; in `bash` 4.x, it defaults to off.

```
% sh -c 'shopt xpg_echo'
xpg_echo        on
% ./sh -c 'shopt xpg_echo'
xpg_echo        off
```

(`./sh` is a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, a local installation of `bash` 4.4 on my machine.)

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the `xpg_echo` option? See item 52 in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode

Comment: That *also* comes into play; I'm not sure if it being enabled by default is the difference between 3.2 and 4.x when `bash` is invoked as `sh`.

Comment: According to [NEWS](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS), `xpg_echo` was introduced in 2.04, and its behaviour being affected by POSIX mode was changed in 3.1. Can't find any changes in 3.2 or later, though.

Comment: Then why does `man sh` show `-n` as a valid option for `echo`?

Comment: @jjj There aren't separate man pages for `sh` and `bash`; `man sh` just shows you the regular `bash` man page. (It would be nice if one could simply explain it by saying that `/bin/sh` is a link (hard or soft) to `/bin/bash`. Unfortunately, they are two separate nodes, so the best one can say is that `/bin/sh` is a `bash` executable that is nearly, but not quite, identical to `/bin/bash`.)

Comment: Ah, you are correct! Seems odd to me that `man echo`, `help echo` and `man bash` all take you to the wrong man pages when you're using `sh`. How do you actually see the man/help for the builtins on `sh`?

Comment: There *is* no separate `sh`; `bash` simply detects if the name it was run under is `sh` and behaves slightly differently, which roughly means being more POSIX compliant.

Comment: Short of reading through the POSIX spec itself, the man page for `dash`  (which you will have to Google for; `dash` is not installed by default on macOS) provides a pretty good proxy for how `sh` should behave.

Comment: `/bin/echo`, by the way, is the BSD implementation, which is not POSIX-compliant in that is supports `-n`.

Comment: I understand, thanks so much. So is there any way to know when you're invoking `echo` using `sh` that `-n` is not actually a valid option? Just wondering how to avoid something like this is the future.

Comment: Not really. The best thing to do is simply avoid `echo` altogether, and use `printf`, the behavior of which is much more predictable.

Comment: `printf` was actually my solution, haha. Thanks again!

Comment: @jjj Using `printf` is also the POSIX recommendation, see the "Application Usage" section in the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: The quote in the original question mentions that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The -n option on echo is supported on my Mac (Big Sur) using zsh.

```
% echo Hello World
Hello World
% echo -n Hello World
Hello World**%**
%
```

The bold percent symbol is because for partial lines zsh goes to the next line to avoid covering it with the prompt.

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting

> by default you will see an inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line: a "%" for a normal user or a "#" for root.